# {select: false} works differently on mongoose queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a user in mongoose and return it after User.create query without password field. I set "select: false" on password field in model schema but it keeps returning me password in response after User.create.

```
// models/user.js

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minlength: 5,
    select: false,
  },
});

// routes/index.js

routes.post(
  "/sign-up",
  celebrate({
    body: Joi.object().keys({
      name: Joi.string().min(2).max(30),
      about: Joi.string().min(2).max(30),
      avatar: Joi.string().pattern(RegExp(urlChecker)),
      email: Joi.string().required().email(),
      password: Joi.string().required().min(5),
    }),
  }),
  usersController.createUser,
);

// controllers/user.js

const User = require("../models/user");

exports.createUser = (req, res, next) => {
  const {
    name,
    about,
    avatar,
    email,
    password,
  } = req.body;
  bcrypt
    .hash(password, 10)
    .then((hash) => User.create({
      name,
      about,
      avatar,
      email,
      password: hash,
    }))
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        throw new InvalidInputError("Invalid data");
      }
      res.send(user); // response includes password field
    })
    .catch((err) => next(err));
};
```

However, if I add User.findById query after User.create, I get a response without password field.

```
// controllers/user.js

    // ...
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        throw new InvalidInputError("Invalid data");
      }
      return User.findById(user._id);
    })
    .then((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        throw new NotFoundError("User not found");
      }
      res.send(user); // works fine!
    })
```

Am I right that {select: false} works only on find queries in mongoose? Are there any other workarounds for not returning password field after User.create method?

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi thx, it works! But the question "Am I right that {select: false} works only on find queries in mongoose? " still remains open

Answer (score 1):

the result of save is a object model, you should convert it to a object and delete password key, like this:

```
user = user.toObject()
delete user.password
res.send(user); // response includes password field
```